# Extention method not assigning value

Tags: c#, extension-methods, variable-assignment

I have a custom sort method for my dataset. I call it like this:

ds.Sort("column");

where ds is of type dataset. Then I sort the first table (sorting code itself is not relevant as the breakpoint shows the result is correct). My sort method looks like this:

```
public static void Sort(this DataSet ds, string column)
{
    DataSet newDs = ds.Copy();

    //sorting occurs

    ds = newDs.Copy();
} // <- breakpoint
```

At the place of breakpoint both ds and newDs have everything sorted like it should. However once I move forward and get to the line after calling this sort method, ds is no longer sorted. I also tried the same with simply doing

```
ds.Clear();
```

in that Sort method and this time it worked. Am I not allowed to assign a value to the object? Is it possible to do this in some way?

Comment: I never tried it with `DataSet`, but does it work? `ds = ds.Sort("column");`

Comment: This is not a proper answer, but is there any problem with just returning a copy of newDs?

Comment: I wanted to make it as short as possible. Also, `ds = ` part will be often forgotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I not allowed to assign a value to the object?

You're not assigning a value to an *object*. You're assigning a value to a *variable*... and that variable is a parameter. Changes to that parameter value are not seen outside the method, as C# uses pass-by-value by default. So for example, consider this code:

```
static void Foo(string input)
{
    input = "In Foo";
}
...
string text = "hello";
Foo(text);
Console.WriteLine(text); // Still prints "hello"
```

If you don't understand that, read [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

You probably want something like this:

```
public static DataSet CopyAndSort(this DataSet ds, string column)
{
    DataSet newDs = ds.Copy();

    //sorting occurs
    return newDs; // No need to copy it *again*.
}
```

Then you can use:

```
ds = ds.CopyAndSort("column");
```

Comment: There will be countless of times I will forget the `ds =` part though :(

Comment: Jon, does `static void Foo(string input)` works like `extension method`? And `extesion method` different only with `chain calls` and `this` argument pass?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Then you'll need to think of another approach. Do you definitely *need* to take a copy rather than sorting in place?

Comment: @FSou1: No, that's not an extension method - but the fact that the OP's method is an extension method is just adding confusion here, I think.

Comment: Sorting in place is fine, however, I know how to sort the only way and that is as follows: `DataView view = ds.Tables[0].AsDataView(); view.Sort = sort; ds.Tables.RemoveAt(0); ds.Tables.Add(view.ToTable());`. So I wanted once and for all make it short. (I guess this approach is NOT in-place one? Or is it?). Now that I look at this, I think I can solve my sorting without needing to assign the newly-made dataset. I will, instead, have it as a temporary storage for data.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: Why don't you just use the view instead of the table directly?

Comment: @JonSkeet In short, I will later need it as a dataset.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius: It's still *in* the dataset... just ask for the view from the table. It's still not clear to me *why* you're creating a new copy in your extension method though. Presumably your "sorting occurs" code changes the contents of the dataset, so why not just do that directly on `ds`? Do you understand *why* the current code doesn't work?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I do now understand why it didn't work for me. And now I realize I didn't need a copy of the dataset at all. Adjusted my method so it only applies changes to ds as suggested (did a bit differently, but the idea is the same) by dasblinkenlight. Thank you for taking your time and explaining it thoroughly :) I ended up needing only `ds.Sort("column")` (without the `ds = ` part), so it's a small win :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between

```
ds.Clear();
```

and

```
ds = newDs.Copy();
```

is that the first operates on the `DataSet` object that you have passed in through a reference `ds`, while the second one re-assigns a new object to that variable, making the original object inaccessible to your extension method.

You can use `Merge` method as a backdoor for filling the original data set with sorted data:

```
ds.Reset();
ds.Merge(newDs);
```

This will work, because the data would be copied into the original `DataSet`.